# comparing max-min values java

Tags: java

I wanted to know what the most efficient way of going through an array of integers was. I am trying find out whether or not each element in a array is followed by a number that is either larger or smaller than it.

For example:

```
int[] c  = {0,2,1,7,5};      

static boolean saw(int[] a){
        int counter = 0;
        int local_max = a[0]
        for (int x = 1; x < a.length - 1; x++){
            if (a[x] < local_max) {
                if (!(a[x + 1] < local_max)) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (a[x] == local_max){// in case there is a plateau
                return false;
            } else {
                a[x] = local_max;
            }
        }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Your statement of requirements is too vague / poorly described to know whether your code meets them.  From an efficiency perspective, the code cannot be improved on, but that is no help if it is incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @StephenC . The OP question is vague. If you are looking to find whether or not each element in a array is followed by a number that is either larger or smaller than it, is it not enough to just see if all the elements in the array are equal ?